# How to dynamically create a radio button with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am pulling data and with ajax and displaying in a form. If a user clicks on any result returned from ajax, it updates an input field. Now instead of only displaying the names on the list, I want to include radio button alongside each name.

Here is my code.

```
$(function() {
$('#searchpartno').keyup(function() {
    var item = $(this).val();
    var item_value = $('#price_luitem_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/searchpartno_stock",
        "data": {"partnumber":item,"luitem_id":item_value},
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(items) {
            $('#partnumber_tbody').empty();
            var clearHTML = '<tr>' +'<td></td>' +'</tr>';
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                trHTML += '<tr>' +'<td onclick="updatePartNo(this)" class="partspare_list">' + item.partnum + '</td>' +'</tr>';
            });
            $('#partnumber_tbody').append(clearHTML);
            $('#partnumber_tbody').append(trHTML);
        },
        "error": function() {
            $('#dailysale_price').val('');
        }
    });
})
})
```

Here is the output
[image: Ajax results]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not save yourself the trouble and do all that server-side?

Comment: I didn't think about. Besides, Am still a newbie in ROR.

Comment: Well, for my money, it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending the partnum as a text , create a radio button the same way you create the tr and td

```
 $.each(items, function (i, item) {
    trHTML += '<tr>' +
              '<td onclick="updatePartNo(this)" class="partspare_list">' +
                '<input type="radio" name="itemnum" value="' + item.partnum 
              + '">' + item.partnum + '<br>' +
              '</td>' +
              '</tr>';
 });
```

Comment: Its giving me an error on the closing '</tr>';. Its expecting a new line or a semicolon.

Comment: Opps , Just fixed

Comment: Thanks. Now the jquery that was getting the clicked name and updating another input is no longer running. Look at the console.log : http://localhost:3000/modalsearchpartno?partno_search=<input+name="itemnum"+value="00000000AH"+type="radio">00000000AH<br>

Comment: This is working. But when I click the name, the radio button doesn't get selected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add radio input like following :

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
       trHTML += '<tr>
                   <td onclick="updatePartNo(this)" class="partspare_list">
                     <input type="radio" name="itemRd" value="'+i+'">
                     ' + item.partnum + '
                   </td>
                 </tr>';
});
```